# How to make a column that fit all the screen in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[image: ui]

I am starting flutter but I cannot figure out how to divide by 2 a column widget and make it fit all the screen as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue)),
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How it is done:

1. I am running an app via the runApp method
2. I create a column and place essentially containers with the colours in it
3. But the containers don't have any size, so they are not visible
4. With the expanded widget I let a widget know to be as big as possible.
5. As I have two expanded widgets, they have the same size.

Voila
[Screenshot from emulator device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWXfS.png)